# How do I handle these C warnings?

Tags: c, warnings, variable-assignment, declaration, implicit

So, I'm getting a few warnings when compiling a C file that I can't figure out how to fix.

The first warning comes from the following  code:

```
char line[100];
char* carbonCopy;
char *currentWord;
wordlist *theList = malloc(sizeof(wordlist));
theList->head->string = NULL;
word *fromFile = malloc(sizeof(word));

while(fgets(line,99,file)){
    if(line != NULL){
        carbonCopy = line;

        while((currentWord = strsep(&line, " ")) !=NULL)
        {
            malloc(strlen(currentWord)*sizeof(char));
            fromFile->string = currentWord;
            fromFile->next = malloc(sizeof(word));
```

The warning states:

> passing argument 1 of 'strsep' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but `strlen` has O(n) running time, so it's generally a bad idea to use it in a loop condition.

Comment: try using string.h and stdlib.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strsep()` expects a `char **` as first argument, but your sources use `char (*)[100]`.

Mod your code like for example this way:

```
char line[100];
char * carbonCopy;

...

carbonCopy = line;
while((currentWord = strsep(&carbonCopy, " ")) !=NULL)
```

Please note that `carbonCopy`is not a copy of `line` but just a reference to it, that said, it points to the data that `line` contains.

---

This line

```
malloc(strlen(currentWord)*sizeof(char));
```

has no effect, but wasting memory.

Comment: @user1795374: Anyway, we see to few code to actually solve the problem for you.

Comment: Should I make carbonCopy a char**? I yielded the same results from switching it from line to carbonCopy

Comment: I bet you missed the leading `&`.

Comment: The address operator `&` makes a `char **` from a `char *`, so `char * charbonCopy; ... strsep(&charbonCopy, ...` shall work.

Comment: It doesn't. I have the exact same thing that you suggested, but the error remains the same

Comment: I think I might have found the cause, thanks to your help though. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the header which declares `strsep` and `strlen`

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: I did forget to do this, thank you. That being said, I'm getting a warning stating that the first argument passed into strsep is an incompatible pointer type.

Comment: Can you update your question to show more code, particularly the type of `line`?

Comment: Yes, I'll update the question, since the previous warnings aren't there anymore, give me one sec